# How to get the related column value, Django

Tags: django

I've looked at various posts on this, but I'm still failing to get the contents of a related column.

I have 2 tables related by a foreign key. I've added a related name - `locations`.

```
# models.py
class Container(models.Model): #like a friend
    container_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    container_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    container_type = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    location_id = models.ForeignKey(Location, db_column='location_id', on_delete = models.PROTECT, related_name = 'locations')
    icon_desc = models.ForeignKey(Icon, db_column='icon_desc', null=True, blank=True, default='Box',on_delete = models.PROTECT)
    samples = models.ManyToManyField('Sample', through='ContainerSamples')

class Location(models.Model):
    location_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    store_id = models.ForeignKey(Storage, db_column='store_id', on_delete = models.PROTECT)
    icon_desc = models.ForeignKey(Icon, db_column='icon_desc', on_delete = models.PROTECT, null=True, blank=True)
    location_type = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    location_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    orderby = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

My views returns `container`

```
# views.py
    def allcontainer(request):
    allcontainer = Container.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'container/allcontainer.html',
     {
        'container':allcontainer
    })
```

And in my template:

```
    {% for contents in container_contents %}
     <p>{{ contents.sample_id }}</p>
    <p>{{ contents.area_easting }}.
      {{ contents.area_northing }}.
      {{ contents.context_number }}.
      {{ contents.sample_number }}</p>
```

I want to add the Locations, I've tried the following:..

```
    <p>{{ contents.locations.location_name }}</p>

{% end for %}
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Is your template correct? It uses completely different fields.

Comment: And anyway, you should call your related field by `contents.location_id.location_name`. `related_name` is used for backwards accessing, as per [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects)

Comment: That did the trick, I added the wrong view, been a long day, I'll review this once I figure out what I've just done!

Comment: Don't name FKs like `location_id`. Name it `location` - `_id` will be appended to physical column name automatically. So, `location` is for representing linked object, `location_id` - for scalar value with linked object id, both are available in model instance all the time. Currently you have inconsistent naming and need to keep in mind to never foget `db_column='location_id'` to avoid `location_id_id`. The same applies to `store_id`.